# How can i compare and concat two arrays on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets say i had two arrays

`a.["mark@example.com", "bob@example.com"]`

`b.["carl@example.com", "mark@example.com", "bob@example.com", "josh@example.com"]`

How can i make a third array, using the variables that are present in the second one, but not on the first one?

the desired output should be this:

`c.["carl@example.com", "josh@example.com"]`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arrayA = ["mark@example.com", "bob@example.com"]
const arrayB = ["carl@example.com", "mark@example.com", "bob@example.com", "josh@example.com"]
const arrayC = arrayB.filter(x => !arrayA.includes(x))
console.log(arrayC)
```